# How to fix the bug with the position of background?

Tags: html, css, svg, background

[image]

The part of the border is hidden. I tried to use different variable of `background-position`. But it didn't help me.

Example of code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.item_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 270px;
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/6MZ.svg);
  min-height: 270px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item_wrapper">
    <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, voluptas dicta aut hic dolorum quam ex consequuntur esse vel cum voluptatem tempora expedita molestias optio necessitatibus reiciendis asperiores odio blanditiis!</div>
  <div class="items">Tenetur minus cumque enim est in aliquam quam blanditiis obcaecati quae aut quis, ratione rerum facere accusantium? Quos eum, sequi odit exercitationem beatae iusto fugiat maxime nulla a laboriosam rem!</div>
  <div class="items">Necessitatibus voluptatum quisquam placeat. Provident quo ut autem voluptatibus assumenda odit maxime rerum! Porro vitae omnis nemo eveniet aspernatur, iste veniam placeat repudiandae. Ab exercitationem non eligendi hic doloremque accusantium?</div>
  <div class="items">Id voluptas architecto quisquam nobis. Nisi, dicta, deleniti maxime atque aperiam, fuga reprehenderit cum ex numquam voluptatum totam? Quisquam fugit numquam accusantium temporibus iusto. Vel quasi cupiditate magni excepturi recusandae!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. In the example the bottom border is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force the background size to cover available width and height. In order to achieve that you must specify the background size: `background-size: 100% 100%;` so it will fill its container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.item_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 270px;
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/6MZ.svg);
  min-height: 270px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item_wrapper">
    <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, voluptas dicta aut hic dolorum quam ex consequuntur esse vel cum voluptatem tempora expedita molestias optio necessitatibus reiciendis asperiores odio blanditiis!</div>
  <div class="items">Tenetur minus cumque enim est in aliquam quam blanditiis obcaecati quae aut quis, ratione rerum facere accusantium? Quos eum, sequi odit exercitationem beatae iusto fugiat maxime nulla a laboriosam rem!</div>
  <div class="items">Necessitatibus voluptatum quisquam placeat. Provident quo ut autem voluptatibus assumenda odit maxime rerum! Porro vitae omnis nemo eveniet aspernatur, iste veniam placeat repudiandae. Ab exercitationem non eligendi hic doloremque accusantium?</div>
  <div class="items">Id voluptas architecto quisquam nobis. Nisi, dicta, deleniti maxime atque aperiam, fuga reprehenderit cum ex numquam voluptatum totam? Quisquam fugit numquam accusantium temporibus iusto. Vel quasi cupiditate magni excepturi recusandae!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make background-size: contain, it will fix your issue.